# Separate OMC and GCC building with OpenModelica script

Tags: gcc, modelica, openmodelica

From a Modelica model, I would like to launch only the OpenModelicaCompiler (OMC) to have the C files results. Then I could manually modify the C-files (mainly to secure my code). After this I would like to use only GCC to compile my C-files to .exe-files...

This is the classic build with the "buidlModel()" openModelica script but i want to separate the two steps "Compile in C" and "Compile in .exe".

Is there any script for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should not need a script.  Just do this:

```
omc -s yourmodel.mo
```

and according to the omc help:

```
  omc -s Model.mo          will produce simulation code for the model:
                            * Model.c           The model C code.
                            * Model_functions.c The model functions C code.
                            * Model.makefile    The makefile to compile the model.
                            * Model_init.xml    The initial values.
```

then you can edit the c files as you want followed by make.

Comment: This, or use the translateModel command (like buildModel, but skips compilation).